# Add address from Google search or maps

Tags: contacts, contact-shortcut

On iOS, as  limited as it was, I  could do two things that I can't figure out how to do in Android  - htc one m8

1. When finding addresses in Google search or map, Google result page had an option to save a contact.   That seems missing in Android.   I can't figure out how to add an address from these results.
2. In ios, whenever I receive an address as plain text in email or sms or web page, I was able to long press and ios would give me option to add the info to a new or existing contact.  I have no way of doing this in Android.  I am forced to manually copy ever line to a contact.

Any suggestions to resolve this would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

The user teresaw has posted years ago a possible solution in this [forum](https://productforums.google.com/forum/m/%23!topic/maps/_lzET53LVHo) :

> I believe if you use Google Maps on an Android device, you can merge an address with an existing contact:
>   1. Search for the address
>   2. Select the address to open more details about that place
>   3. Click on 'Add as a contact'
>   4. This will prompt you to add this address as a new contact. HOWEVER, if you press on the Menu button (on Android devices), you will see an option to 'Join'.
>   5. You can then select any existing contacts and add this new address. Just make sure to enter in the correct Name.
>
> I am not pretty sure if this still works but back then it was really helpful for me.

Comment: Comment from [Adam Felson](http://android.stackexchange.com/users/79178/adam-felson) (lacking rep to comment himself): *add as a contact is no longer available since maps 7 / android > 4.2.2*

Comment: Available again (Maps 9 / Android 6).